# Email Services for Web APP

Tags: email, smtp, notifications, postmark

I need a total email system for my web application.

1. Newsletter delivery once per month.
2. Notifications when a user has registered with the web app or performed an action within it.

There will be approx 200,000 subscribers to the newsletter running over a period of 4 months sending 1 email per month.

There will be approx 500,000 notification emails sent over the 4 months.

Currently my web app infrastructure is based around a load balanced system which makes it difficult to send the notification emails reliably regarding reverse DNS... is there a clever way around this?

I'm looking at [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) for the newsletter management and [postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com/) for the notification emails but pricing seems quite expensive. Is there a service which can combine both of these requirements? Or any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to stick with separating the two just because you don't want to have your emails get mixed up when you are sending them. This is largely in terms of deliverability - if you have customers clicking on "Spam" for your bulk emails, it might affect their ability to receive your transactional emails or emails in general.

I prefer [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) over Campaign Monitor because of how awesome their service is and the sort of metrics you get back for newsletters.

I am the Product Manager of [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com), so if you have any further questions about what you are trying to do, feel free to reach out and let me know if I can answer anything for you.